# Reading cells and writing them to a different column with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First off I'd really like to thank you if you are reading this question.

My problem is that I can not make Excel read the cells in each row with VBA and, if it finds the data in the cell same as the previous processed one, I want it to be written beside column of first found same cell.

Here are some images on which I require:

[First Stage][http://i61.tinypic.com/m8ekqg.png[/IMG]](http://i61.tinypic.com/m8ekqg.png%5b/IMG%5d)
[What is needed to be done][http://i58.tinypic.com/260vltg.png[/IMG]](http://i58.tinypic.com/260vltg.png%5b/IMG%5d)

I will really appreciate if you can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. You may need to update range references etc.

```
Sub ProcessData()
    Dim data As Range, arr() As Variant, i As Long, rw As Long

    Set data = Range("A2:C9")
    arr() = data
    rw = 2
    data.ClearContents

    For i = 1 To data.Rows.Count
        If i = 1 Then
            Range("A" & rw) = arr(i, 1)
            Range("B" & rw) = arr(i, 2)
            Range("C" & rw) = arr(i, 3)
        ElseIf arr(i, 1) <> arr(i - 1, 1) Then
            rw = rw + 1
            Range("A" & rw) = arr(i, 1)
            Range("B" & rw) = arr(i, 2)
            Range("C" & rw) = arr(i, 3)
        Else
            With Range("A" & rw).End(xlToRight)
                .Offset(0, 1) = arr(i, 2)
                .Offset(0, 2) = arr(i, 3)
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```